# Filtering 2D JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I am reading some JSON into a 2D JS object as follows:

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(arr) {
    dict = arr;
});
```

Example when I do console.log(dict[1]); - there are thousands of such rows:

```
{
    "ortho": "a",
    "phon": "a",
    "lemme": "a",
    "cgram": "NOM",
    "genre": "m",
    "nombre": "",
    "freqlemfilms2": "81.36",
    "freqlemlivres": "58.65",
    "freqfilms2": "81.36",
    "_freqlivres": "58.65",
    "_infover": "",
    "_nbhomogr": "3",
    "_nbhomoph": "9",
    "_islem": "1",
    "_nblettres": "1",
    "_nbphons": "1",
    "_cvcv": "V",
    "_p_cvcv": "V",
    "_voisorth": "25",
    "_voisphon": "20",
    "_puorth": "1",
    "_puphon": "1",
    "_syll": "a",
    "_nbsyll": "1",
    "_cv-cv": "V",
    "_orthrenv": "a",
    "_phonrenv": "a",
    "_orthosyll": "a",
    "_cgramortho": "NOM,AUX,VER",
    "_deflem": "",
    "_defobs": "",
    "_old20": "1",
    "_pld20": "1",
    "_morphoder": "a",
    "_nbmorph": "1",
    "no": "1"
}
```

I'm then trying to filter this to yield all rows (result) where orth is a particular value.

```
const asArray = Object.entries(dict);
const result = asArray.filter(word => word.ortho === 'a');
console.log(result);
```

This yields an empty array although I know there are several results.  Please could someone advise what I've missed out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your use of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). `Object.entries` returns an array of `[key, value]` tuples, so your filter callback doesn't make sense as it is. (It is trying to access `ortho` on an array...`[1, {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a", ... }].ortho`)

Instead, if `dict` is an object, you need to filter the `dict` values.

```
const dict = { 1: {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a", }, 2: {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a",},}

const result = Object.values(dict).filter(word => word.ortho === 'a');
```

```js
const dict = { 1: { ortho: 'a', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm', nombre: '', }, 2: { ortho: 'g', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm', }, 3: { ortho: 'b', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', }, };

const result = Object.values(dict).filter((word) => word.ortho === 'a');

console.log(result);
```

I've only guessed that `dict` is an object from your inferences, if it is actually an array, then just filter it directly.

```
const dict = [ {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a", }, {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a",},]

const result = dict.filter((word) => word.ortho === 'a');
```

```js
const dict = [ { ortho: 'a', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm', nombre: '' }, { ortho: 'a', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm' }, { ortho: 'b', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM' },];

const result = dict.filter((word) => word.ortho === 'a');

console.log(result);
```

**Edit**  (In response to your comment re: filtering by an array)

If you want to filter for multiple values you can declare an array and use [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the value is included.

```
const dict = [ {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a", }, {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a",},];

const filter_array = ['a', 'c'];
const result = dict.filter((word) => filter_array.includes(word.ortho));
```

```js
const dict = [
  { ortho: 'a', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm', nombre: '' },
  { ortho: 'b', phon: 'b', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm' },
  { ortho: 'c', phon: 'c', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM' },
  { ortho: 'd', phon: 'd', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM' },
];

const filter_array = ['a', 'c'];
const result = dict.filter((word) => filter_array.includes(word.ortho));

console.log(result);
```

Or, if you wanted to also specify the properties to you could declare an array of `[key, value]` tuples to check against in your filter call. Here using [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which will match if any matches are found, but you could replace it with [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) if you wanted only elements that match all conditions.

```
const dict = [ {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a", }, {"ortho": "a", "phon": "a",},]


const filter_tuples = [['ortho', 'a'],['phon', 'b'],];
const result = dict.filter((word) => filter_tuples.some(([k, v]) => word[k] === v));
```

```js
const dict = [
  { ortho: 'a', phon: 'a', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm', nombre: '' },
  { ortho: 'b', phon: 'b', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM', genre: 'm' },
  { ortho: 'c', phon: 'c', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM' },
  { ortho: 'd', phon: 'd', lemme: 'a', cgram: 'NOM' },
];

const filter_tuples = [['ortho', 'a'],['phon', 'b'],];
const result = dict.filter((word) => filter_tuples.some(([k, v]) => word[k] === v));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation.  As an aside, could I ask how I would go about extending this example for multiple words - so instead of 'a', an array of words? Do I then need to start thinking about using key/value pairs?

`const result = asArray.filter(function(word){
                        return arr.indexOf(word.ortho) > 0;
                    });`

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. I'll add an array example.

Comment: Added some further examples. Hopefully this gives you some idea of patterns to use for further uses.